# MooseX::Types declaration issue, tight test case :)

Tags: perl, moose, moosex-types

So after an embarrassing amount of time debugging, I've finally stripped [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621589/perl-moose-typedecorator-error-how-do-i-debug) down to a simple test case.  I would humbly request some help understanding why it's failing. :)  Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
plxc16479> $h2/tmp/tmp18.pl
This method [new] requires a single argument. at /nfs/pdx/disks/nehalem.pde.077/perl/5.12.2/lib64/site_perl/MooseX/Types/TypeDecorator.pm line 91

MooseX::Types::TypeDecorator::new('MooseX::Types::TypeDecorator=HASH(0x655b90)') called at /nfs/pdx/disks/nehalem.pde.077/projects/lib/Program-Plist-Pl/lib/Program/Plist/Pl.pm line 10

Program::Plist::Pl::BUILD('Program::Plist::Pl=HASH(0x63d478)', 'HASH(0x63d220)') called at generated method (unknown origin) line 29

Program::Plist::Pl::new('Program::Plist::Pl') called at /nfs/pdx/disks/nehalem.pde.077/tmp/tmp18.pl line 10
```

Wrapper test script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {push(@INC, split(':', $ENV{PERL_TEST_LIBS}))};

use Program::Plist::Pl;

my $obj = Program::Plist::Pl->new();
```

Program::Plist::Pl file:

```
package Program::Plist::Pl;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

use Program::Types qw(Pattern); # <-- Removing this fixes error
use Program::Plist::Pl::Pattern;

sub BUILD {
  my $pattern_obj = Program::Plist::Pl::Pattern->new();
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

Program::Types file:

```
package Program::Types;

use MooseX::Types -declare => [qw(Pattern)];

class_type Pattern, {class => 'Program::Plist::Pl::Pattern'};

1;
```

And the Program::Plist::Pl::Pattern file:

```
package Program::Plist::Pl::Pattern;

use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

Notes: While I don't need the `Pattern` type from `Program::Types` in the above code, I do in other code that is stripped out.  The `PERL_TEST_LIBS` env var from which I'm pulling `INC` paths only contains paths to the project modules.  There are no other modules loaded from these paths.

It appears the [MooseX::Types](http://p3rl.org/MooseX::Types) definition for `Pattern` is causing problems, but I'm not sure why.  Documentation shows the syntax I am using, but it's possible I'm misusing `class_type` as there isn't much said about it.  Intent is to be able to use `Pattern` for type checking via [MooseX::Params::Validate](http://p3rl.org/MooseX::Params::Validate) to verify the argument is a `Program::Plist::Pl::Program` object.

I've found that removing the intervening class `Program::Plist::Pl` from the equation by directly calling `Pattern->new` from the `tmp18.pl` wrapper results in no error, even when the `Program::Types` `Pattern` type is imported.

Comment: It would seem that Program::Plist::Pl::Pattern->new is being mistaken for Pattern->new, where Pattern is my MooseX defined type.  So instead of creating an instance of Program::Plist::Pl::Pattern, it's trying to create an instance of the Pattern type object.

Answer (score 5):

When you say

```
package Program::Plist::Pl;
...
use Program::Types qw(Pattern);
```

you are importing a subroutine named `Pattern` into package `Program::Plist::Pl`.  Its fully-qualified name is `Program::Plist::Pl::Pattern`.  Therefore,

```
Program::Plist::Pl::Pattern->new();
```

parses as

```
Program::Plist::Pl::Pattern()->new();
```

instead of

```
'Program::Plist::Pl::Pattern'->new();
```

which is what you meant.  You can write that with explicit quotes if you want (and it will work), but it's an annoying special case.  Another solution is to rename the type to something that won't conflict with the package name (say `PatternObj`).

[namespace::autoclean](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?namespace::autoclean) doesn't help with this.  It prevents people from calling imported subs as methods.  But you're calling `Program::Plist::Pl::Pattern()` directly, and then calling a method on its return value.

Comment: This, incidentally, is an excellent reason to follow Perl's "community standard" naming conventions: TitleCase class names, lowercase_sub_names_with_underscores.  If you use TitleCase for both class names and sub names, clashes like this are *extremely* likely due to the frequency of object attributes named after the right-most component of class names (e.g., $product->Vendor() used to get/set a Product::Vendor object).

Comment: cjm -- Yeah, it seems obvious now that I have the bug cornered :)  I'm just glad to have finally determined what was going on.  This drove me nuts for DAYS.  But I also learned more in that time then I've learned in quite a while :)

John -- You are absolutely correct on the naming standards.  I follow them on all my code.  However, I've never used Moose before and all documentation I've seen uses the UpperCase type naming convention for type definitions, so I used what was the apparent naming protocol.